# Track select option menu URL redirects in Universal Analytics

Tags: javascript, redirect, google-analytics, cross-domain, universal-analytics

I'm looking to track via Universal Analytics a select option menu, which when a certain value is selected then the user is automatically greeted with a message stating they will be redirected to a new domain and then they are sent to another domain (*cross-domain tracking needed*). The current code for the menu I have is:

```
<select id="menuredirect" name="menu"> 
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="externalurl">3</option>
</select>
```

What would be the best way of achieving this so I can pass the Universal Analytics cookie data on to the new domain on this redirect and avoid self-referrals?

Would *Google Tag Manager* be able to decorate the URL on redirect if a JavaScript redirect is used?

Answer (score 0):

The submit handler tag in GTM decorates the form action, not urls in javascript functions. You would need to get the client-id and append it to the redirect url in your redirect function

[According to the documentation you get the client id](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/domains#getClientId) like this:

ga(function(tracker) {
  var clientId = tracker.get('clientId');
});

A [real life implementation is discussed in this thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/analytics/B6oiadB0PZk) in the GTM support forum.